# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when makin a sitemap using react-router-sitemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, sitemap

i followed this [blog](https://blog.josedromero.com/create-sitemap-for-your-react-app/) because my goal is to generate a sitemap but i get an error when i run npm run sitemap:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/maurijnvd/discord_bots/geld-verdienen.nl/src/router.js: Unexpected token (5:2)
  3 | 
  4 | export default (
> 5 |   <Switch>
    |   ^
  6 |   <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
  7 |   <Route path='/10-manieren-om-geld-te-verdienen' component={Verdienen}/>
  8 |   <Route path='/hoe-bepaal-je-de-waarde-van-een-sneaker' component={WaardeBepalen}/>
```

this is my App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/pages/Home'
import Verdienen from './components/pages/geld-verdienen'
import WaardeBepalen from './components/pages/sneaker-waarde'
import Navbar from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer'
import Page404 from './components/pages/404Page';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path='/10-manieren-om-geld-te-verdienen' element={<Verdienen/>}/>
          <Route exact path='/hoe-bepaal-je-de-waarde-van-een-sneaker' element={<WaardeBepalen/>}/>
          <Route path='*' element={<Page404/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my router.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import Home from './components/pages/Home'
import Verdienen from './components/pages/geld-verdienen'
import WaardeBepalen from './components/pages/sneaker-waarde'
import Page404 from './components/pages/404Page';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
    <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
    <Route exact path='/10-manieren-om-geld-te-verdienen' element={<Verdienen/>}/>
    <Route exact path='/hoe-bepaal-je-de-waarde-van-een-sneaker' element={<WaardeBepalen/>}/>
    <Route path='*' element={<Page404/>}/>
  </Routes>

  )
}
export default Routes
```

this is my sitemap-builder.js

```
require("@babel/register")({
    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
  });
  const router = require('./router').default;
  const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;
  (
     new Sitemap(router)
        .build("https://mi-awesome-website.com")
        .save('./public/sitemap.xml')
  );
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "geld-verdienen.nl",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sitemap": "babel-node src/sitemap-builder.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest": "^27.5.1"
  }
}
```

I already tried replace  with  but that didn't work.
how can i fix the error? Another way to make a sitemap would also be a good solution
Let me know if you need more information.

Edit: I changed the router.js file because it was outdated

Comment: rename your js file to jsx

Comment: @DanielA.White didn't work sadly, still the same error.

Comment: `react-router-sitemap` appears to be quite dated now, the last update to that project was 4 years ago. It seems like this might be related to a babel configuration. Take a look at the repo's [issues](https://github.com/kuflash/react-router-sitemap/issues) if anyone else has had this issue. You might need to move along and find a different site map generator.

Comment: Any updates on this, because I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Hello @maurijn.vd can you try this? Move the router.js out of the src folder, and also make sure the sitemap-builder.js file is in the same level. Make sure to update the package.json in the script section to reflect the changes. Then in the router.js file inside the return, update the wrapper `<Routes>` to `<Switch>` with their corresponding closing tags. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention in your router.js file remove all the `exact and element={<Home/>}` just leave the path. From this `<Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>` to this`<Route path='/' />`